# Fluid not interacting with obstacle correctly Blender 2.8

Tags: fluid-simulation

Fluid acts as if the obstacle is in a different location and orientation. Any fixes?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you move the obstacle? have applied any transforms?

Comment: 2.82 will hopefully bring mantaflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your file and you need to aplly transforms yo all the objects that interact with your fluid simulation, also you should tweak some settings inside the parameters of fluids in order to get better results, also adding some geometry with simple subdiv (not catmull-clark).

Also use larger dimensions, Blender works better in simulations with larger objects.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!